# aapt2 link errors about resource files not found

Tags: android, aapt2

While trying to use aapt2 to link some resources, I got this error message `error: resource drawable/googleg_standard_color_18 (aka com.google.android.gms.auth.api:drawable/googleg_standard_color_18) not found.` and other similar messages about some files not found.

Where can I find these resource files that aapt2 needs?

Comment: show build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

The error about the resource not found in your project which you are trying to use.
put the needed icon or resource in your drawable folder and try to use it.